# Ionic 3 - float image to the right side of container

Tags: css, ionic3

My app looks like [this](https://moblize.it/).

Notice the header image is left aligned with the code. Even float is right. How do I fix it?

```
<ion-slides direction="vertical" speed="1000" slidesPerView="1">
  <ion-slide  class="site-slide"  style="background-color:#2298D3">
    <ion-card style="height:300px;float:right">
      <img src="http://www.segalpetroniru.com/images/Consulting-Services-Hero-Image-Secondary.jpg" />
    </ion-card>
  </ion-slide>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
.swiper-slide img {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    float: right;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add [`float-right`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-utilities/#float-elements) to your `<img>`-tag:

```
<img src="yourUrl" float-right/>
```

This will make your image float to the right side of the containing element.